# Error while installing flask framework on ubuntu 15.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, flask

I am trying to install flask framework on my ubuntu 15.04. It is giving me this error and I am unable to figure it out. It would be great if someone could help

Error:

```
pragati@pragati-ubuntu:~/Python-2.7.11$ sudo pip install flask
[sudo] password for pragati: 
Downloading/unpacking flask
  Downloading Flask-0.10.1.tar.gz (544kB): 544kB downloaded
Cleaning up...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 304, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1230, in prepare_files
    req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 293, in run_egg_info
    logger.notify('Running setup.py (path:%s) egg_info for package %s' % (self.setup_py, self.name))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 266, in setup_py
    import setuptools
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/setuptools-18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/setuptools/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from setuptools.extension import Extension
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/setuptools-18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/setuptools/extension.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/setuptools-18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/setuptools/dist.py", line 21, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'packaging'

Storing debug log for failure in /home/pragati/.pip/pip.log
```

Comment: Word of advice for posting questions: if you format your errors nicely, greater chance someone will respond.

Answer (score 0):

You need to uninstall the `distribute` library and reinstall it:

```
sudo pip uninstall distribute
```

Then try again.

Comment: Not working... Error:pragati@pragati-ubuntu:~/Python-2.7.11$ sudo pip uninstall distribute
Cannot uninstall requirement distribute, not installed
Storing debug log for failure in /home/pragati/.pip/pip.log

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to compiled files.
Try deleting your *.pyc files and rerun the install.

My other suggestion (as it doesn't appear you are) is that you should use a virtual environment so you can avoid having to use `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

This is best way to work. You will protect your python which installed on os while developing projects with python. And you should not use sudo when you activate virtualenv after that you can check which pip or python are you using:

```
which pip
```

[Virtualenv](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/)